# Htmlagilitypack: create html text node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

In HtmlAgilityPack, I want to create `HtmlTextNode`, which is a `HtmlNode` (inherts from HtmlNode) that has a custom InnerText.

```
HtmlTextNode CreateHtmlTextNode(string name, string text)
{
     HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
     HtmlTextNode textNode = doc.CreateTextNode(text);
     textNode.Name = name;
     return textNode;
}
```

The problem is that the `textNode.OuterHtml` and `textNode.InnerHtml` will be equal to "text" after the method above.

e.g. `CreateHtmlTextNode("title", "blabla")` will generate:
`textNode.OuterHtml = "blabla"` instead of `<Title>blabla</Title>`

Is there any better way to create `HtmlTextNode`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `HTMLTextNode` contains just Text, no tags.

It's like the following:

```
<div>                                   - HTML Node
    <span>text</span>                   - HTML Node
    This is the Text Node               - Text Node
    <span>text</span>                   - HTML Node
</div>
```

You're looking for a standard HtmlNode.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode textNode = doc.CreateElement("title");
textNode.InnerHtml = HtmlDocument.HtmlEncode(text);
```

Be sure to call `HtmlDocument.HtmlEncode()` on the text you're adding. That ensures that special characters are properly encoded.

Comment: small correction: HtmlEncode is static is it should be HtmlDocument.HtmlEncode(text). Thanks it works!

Answer (score 23):

The following lines creates a outer html with  content

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

// create html document
var html = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(html);

// select the <head>
var head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head");

// create a <title> element
var title = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<title>Hello world</title>");

// append <title> to <head>
head.AppendChild(title);

// returns Hello world!
var inner = title.InnerHtml;

// returns <title>Hello world!</title>
var outer = title.OuterHtml;
```

Hope it helps.